# Google sheets import columns based on date value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-dates, importrange

Google sheets for simplicity's sake say I have two tabs, one with master data and one that is a search function to display a certain part of the master data. The issue is I only want import certain columns based on the date for exemple first of January i want to import column b-e from master data, next day I want i want to increment it by one, c-f and so on. I would like to use functions like =Today(), -1, +1 but how do I select columns to import based on something that isnt just the letter of the column? Current solution I have to manually change the formula and can only filter the y-axis but not x(columns, other than staticly A-G).

Any ideas would be super helpful.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data. Enter textual descriptions in cells to tell what you want in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would probably be to use `filter()` with a condition parameter that compares `column(Sheet1!A1:Z1)` with your column selection criteria.

Alternatively, you could use `query()` where the data range is given throgh an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276), with a `select` clause that names columns using string manipulation and simple arithmetic.